# Nested attribute_accessible rails or hash in attribute_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I want to be able to create attributes on a ActiveRecord:Base Model that are nested.

For example -

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :operator, :who
```

I would like :who to have further attributes like :family, :me
So finally I can access these as follows

```
book = Book.new
book.who.family = [1,2,3]
book.who.me = 1
```

I also want to know how can I define the kind of values that attributes can take so I do not have to do that at runtime.

Currently am using something like this

```
after_initialize do
   @who = {family: [], me: nil}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in my console. So if you add the your attributes as attribute accessors and after_initialize set them like this.

```
attr_accessor :who, :operator

after_initialize do
  self.who = {family: [], me: nil}
  self.operator = "Minus"
end
```

then you can access them like this

```
self.who[:family] = [1,2,3,4]
```

or

```
self.operator = "Minus"
```

and you can simply access them like this

```
self.who[:family] ==> [1,2,3]
```

Will this help?

Comment: None of :who, :family, :me are stored in the db. They do not need to be. Just need a way to group virtual attributes.

Comment: You want some kind of attr_acessor through which you can just take input from user and have them virtually and use them for some kind of logic.??

Comment: Yes. I want to know how to group virtual attributes

Comment: so i updated my answer as per your requirements. will that help.? im not sure but if you can confirm

Comment: What i am wanting to achieve is something like this attr_accessor :operator, who: [:family, :me] basically in the line for attr_accessible other than standalone symbols can i pass anything else

Comment: im afraid you cant do so, as attr_accessor has to create getter and setter for the attributes you pass comma seperated. and the format you are passing the method does not expect that... it will crash. just a suggestion, why dont you make a method which you call on after_initialize and add all your logic in that.?

Comment: Can do that, just wanted to avoid it.

Comment: i think you should use the method logic, it is more simple, easy to handle. easy to add things in future..:)